# sbt task configurations are lost after update to a new IntelliJ IDEA version

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, sbt, upgrade

I have a list of saved sbt task configurations in my IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3. It looks like this in the upper-right corner of the IDE window:

[image: screenshot1]

However, when I upgrade to IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1, those tasks cannot be recognized by the ide, and my list turns into something like this:

[image]

Not one of those "Unknown" entries runs a task. It does not even open a dialog window to fix the configuration.
How do I correctly port my sbt tasks into the new IntelliJ IDEA version so they are not lost?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA stores tasks for each project in `.idea/runConfigurations` subfolder of that project's root folder.
Each saved task has its own `.xml` file in that subfolder. For example, `___clean__compile_.xml`:

```xml
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="&quot;; clean; compile&quot;" type="SbtRunConfiguration" factoryName="SBT Task" show_console_on_std_err="false" show_console_on_std_out="false">
    <option name="allowRunningInParallel" value="false" />
    <option name="tasks" value="&quot;; clean; compile&quot;" />
    <option name="useSbtShell" value="false" />
    <option name="vmparams" value="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled" />
    <option name="workingDir" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
    <method v="2" />
  </configuration>
</component>
```

Note the `factoryName` property of `configuration` node: `factoryName="SBT Task"`.
In IntelliJ 2019, the `factoryName` for sbt tasks was `"sbt Task"`. With version 2020.1, it changed to `"SBT Task"` ("sbt" part became uppercase).
To fix your saved tasks, go through files in your `.idea/runConfigurations/` folder and change `factoryName` in each file to `"SBT Task"`.
Then restart your IntelliJ project, and you should see your sbt tasks working again.